# chebyshev expansion

Tags: real-analysis, power-series, orthogonal-polynomials, chebyshev-polynomials

**Express First kind Chebyshev polynomial in terms of monomials**

I have a function as

**(1)**  $f=\sum_i^n a_iT_i$ ,

where $T_i$ are first kind Chebyshev polynomial of order "i". I want to express $f$ in terms of monomials (powers of x). Hence, I need to write $T_i$ in terms of monomials.This can be done using following recursive formula:
$T_0(x)=1;
T_1(x)=x;
T_{n+1}(x)=2xT_n(x)−T_{n−1}(x)$ for $x \in [-1, 1]$.

So function $f$ in terms of monomials and the original function in (1) should match over $x\in [-1 1]$

**However as "i" increases ($i\ge45$), the two functions do not match.**

For example, following Matlab plots function $f=T_{50}$ both in monomials space and Chebyshev space.

clc;clear;close all;
% f=T_n;

n=50;
x=[-pi:0.1:0];
plot(cos(x),cos((n-1)*x),'k*-')

syms x;
Tr(1,1)=1+0*x; Tr(2,1)=x;
for i=2:n-1; Tr(i+1,1)= expand(2*x*Tr(i,1)-Tr(i-1,1));end;
hold on;for x=-1:0.01:1; plot(x,eval(Tr(end)),'--bo'); end;

Comment: Isn't it an index shift (getting $T_{49}$ instead of $T_{50}$ for example) because, with the classical indexing: $T_0(x)=1$, $T_1(x)=x$, $T_2(x)=2x^2-1$, etc.?

Comment: It is definitely a bad use of this site to ask again a question that you have asked some hours ago (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2413957).